# How to exact match in regular expression where we have same initial words in it

Tags: javascript, regex

I have not that much aware of RegEx but my scenerio is that I have created following regex in javascript.

**RegExp:**

```
var regex1 = RegExp(/(\sClaim\b|^Claim\b|\sAssessment\b|^Assessment\b|\sClaim number\b|^Claim number\b)/ , 'ig');
var str1 = 'what assessment claim number';
var array1;
while ((array1 = regex1.exec(str1)) !== null) {
    console.log(`Found ${array1[0]}. Next starts at 
    ${regex1.lastIndex}.`);
}
```

As we can see that in str1 the string contains claim number but it gives match with only claim so how can we achieve that it will matches claim number instead of claim only.

Answer (score 1):

Put `\sClaim\b` at the end of expression

```
(^Claim\s+number|^Claim|^Assessment|\sClaim\s+number|\sAssessment|\sClaim)\b
```

Note : I used `\s+` for white spaces and corrected orders

Comment: I was about to say it! :)
I looks like it takes the first one that matches in this case.
Also I would put "\b" outside parentheses to simplify a bit.

Comment: @battlmonstr Thanks for `\b` hint.

Comment: Actually I have only given an example the Regular expression is created  dynamically I have already thought about putting claim in the last but point is that it is created dynamically.

Comment: Actually I have only given an example the Regular expression is created  dynamically so we can't change order if it would have then i would have already done it.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have both `Claim` and `Claim number` in your regex alternation.  To workaround your problem, you need to somehow differentiate `Claim` by itself from `Claim number`.  One way to do this would be to use a negative lookahead:

```
var regex1 = RegExp(/(\bClaim\b(?! number)|\bAssessment\b|\bClaim Number\b)/, 'ig');
```

The pattern `\bClaim\b(?! number)` says to match `Claim`, but only if it is *not* followed by `number`.

We could also try to handle this by placing `Claim Number` first in the alternation.  But as we add more terms, this trick might break at some point.  Using a lookahead lets us nail down what we are trying to match.

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Just use `?` quantifier:

```js
var input1 = 'what assessment claim number';
var input2 = 'what assessment claim';
var template = /(assessment\s)?claim(\snumber)?/i;
var match1 = input1.match(template);
var match2 = input2.match(template);
console.log(match1[0]);
console.log(match2[0]);
```